# Dynamic allocation of string arrays in Fortran does not resize

Tags: arrays, string, fortran

Consider the following Fortran program:

```
program test
character(len=:), allocatable :: str
allocate(character(3) :: str)
print *, len(str)
str = '12345'
print *, len(str)
end program
```

When I run this I get the expected result:

```
   3
   5
```

That is, the character string was resized from 3 to 5 when str was set to '12345'. If, instead, I use an array of dynamic strings this is not true. Example:

```
program test
character(len=:), allocatable :: str(:)
allocate(character(3) :: str(2))
print *, len(str(1)), len(str(2))
str(1) = '12345'
print *, len(str(1)), len(str(2))
end program
```

When I run this I get:

```
   3           3
   3           3
```

So the set of str(1) did not change the length the string. I get the same behavior with ifort 16.0.2 and gfortran 5.3.1. My question is this behavior consistent with the latest Fortran standard or is this a bug in the compilers?

Comment: which compilation flags did you use? Try to set boundary checking and warnings (options like -C and -Wall)

Comment: Each element in an allocatable array of strings has the same length. To get an allocatable array of allocatable strings, you can use the technique shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8407272/7038689).

Comment: @albert: No flags were used. See the answer as to why this is the way it is.

Answer (score 5):

This is the correct behaviour. An element of an allocatable array is not itself an allocatable variable and cannot be re-allocated on assignment (or in any other way). Also, all array elements must have the same type - including the string length.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Vladimir F's answer, you could achieve what you have in mind with a few changes to your code, like the following (which creates a jagged array of character vectors):

```
program test

type :: CherVec_type
    character(len=:), allocatable :: str
end type CherVec_type

type(CherVec_type) :: JaggedArray(2)

allocate(character(3) :: JaggedArray(1)%str)
allocate(character(3) :: JaggedArray(2)%str)
print *, len(JaggedArray(1)%str), len(JaggedArray(2)%str)

JaggedArray(1)%str = "12345"
print *, len(JaggedArray(1)%str), len(JaggedArray(2)%str)

end program
```

which creates the following output:

```
$gfortran -std=f2008 *.f95 -o main
$main
       3           3
       5           3
```

Comment: This is similar to the difference between having a "pointer to an array" (the original post) as opposed to having an "array of pointers" (this post).